# C++ accessing private static variable within a static function

Tags: c++, qt, class

I have a class with a static function getSharedInstance, thus should give me a pointer to an already instanced version of the class.

Header:

```
class foo {
public:
  static foo *getSharedInstance();

private:
  static foo *sharedInstance;
}
```

Implementation:

```
foo *foo::getSharedInstance() {
    if(sharedInstance == NULL)
        sharedInstance = new foo();
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

The point I don't understand is, why do I get undefined reference to the variable sharedInstance?

Comment: You need to *define* static data members. You have only *declared* one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to instanciate it somewhere (generally in you class' cpp file):

```
foo *foo::sharedInstance;
```

The compiler assumes it will find the symbol (ie the pointer representing your instance) somewhere. However, if you don't define it, it wont find it and will therefor raise `undefined reference`

Comment: That means, you must do something like:
`foo *foo::sharedInstance = 0;`
in your cpp-file.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've been doing to much php :)